# Different MySQl tables for different languages

Tags: mysql, localization

I am trying to deal with MySQL design. Does it make sense to make few tables instead of one depending on native language of the user?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the schema and use of your intended database, do you plan to have a primary key in one table, that will be referenced by the foreign keys in other tables? Depending on what you are trying to accomplish and the relationships between different entities, will tell you whether to implement one or multiple tables.

Comment: Well, I planned to have a language in general user table. Depending on this, I would query to this or that table with publications.